# Spectral Response of a photo-resistor (CdS) and phototransistor (Si)!

Tags: homework-and-exercises, experimental-physics

I am doing a report on an experiment I took and I have completed every section apart from this last bit. I am told to compare the spectral response of a CdS and Si. I am unable to construct a graph from the information I have, which is current and voltage. I am also given a table with the filters I used for the experiment (ranging from 440nm to 700nm) and I am also given their respective peak transmissions (%). This is where i am stuck and have no idea how to use this!

Help would greatly very appreciated!?

Comment: Do you need help with the definition of spectral response? All the information you need is given or a result of your experiment.

Comment: @paisanco I'm actually not sure why I am given the peak transmission of all the filters? How would I use this?